# Numpy array subtraction creates a matrix with different dimension. How to correct that?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am attempting to create a simply neuronetwork using Python (I know there are libraries, but I'm building a simple one from scratch to get more familiar with each step taken), and one part of it is to calculate the difference between the true label and the predicted label.

I have the true label in dim <2059 x 1>, and the predicted label also in <2059 x 1>

Both are in np.array

I would expect a simple

```
l2_error=tag_train-l2
```

would do the job. (l2 is the predicted label, tag_train is the true label)

but what I got in return is a <2059x2059> matrix. It seems like this operation is doing a subtraction of every possible combination of elements. Why would this happen? I know I can probably run a `for` loop to get the job done, for I'm wondering why the program would produce this result?

Both dtypes are float64, btw. I don't think it matters, but just in case this info is needed.

Comment: You must be wrong about the dimensions.  I suspect tag_train.shape==(2059,1), not (1,2059).  If you work with 1d arrays, you won't run into this problem.

Comment: @Alan I did a test on tag_train.shape and it returned (2059,). Yes, the second element is missing. I think this can be why my subtraction is all messed up, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: `(n,)` automatically expands to `(1,n)` if needed for broadcasting.  What you need is `x[:,None]` to added the 2nd dimension at end to match the other array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated in the comments, what is happening is that `tag_train` is a one dimensional array with length 2059 , whereas `l2` is supposedly a 2 dimensional array with 2059 rows and 1 column.

So when you try to do subtraction it leads to a 2 dimensional array with 2059 rows and 2059 columns.

If you are 100% sure that l2 would only be one column then you can reshape that array to make it one dimensional before doing the subtraction. Like -

```
l2.reshape((l2.shape[0],))
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: l1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [3]: l2 = np.array([[5],[6],[7],[8]])

In [7]: l2.shape
Out[7]: (4, 1)

In [8]: l2-l1
Out[8]:
array([[4, 3, 2, 1],                 #Just to show that you get the behaviour when arrays are in 
       [5, 4, 3, 2],                 #different dimensions.
       [6, 5, 4, 3],
       [7, 6, 5, 4]])

In [19]: l2 = l2.reshape((l2.shape[0],))

In [25]: l2 = l2.reshape((l2.shape[0],))

In [26]: l2-l1
Out[26]: array([4, 4, 4, 4])
```

Comment: I see, so dimension does become the problem. I always thought the program would autoadjust it as long as there are the same amount of elements in the two arrays (so (2059,) would be the same as (2059,1)). 
One question: would it be a good practice to reshape the tag_train into a 2D array first?

Comment: Yea, you can do that also, it basically depends on your needs. If you want to use tag_train as a 2d array later as well, that maybe the way to go.